# File names to indicate pseudo directories using mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to use file name strings as an indicator for mod_rewrite to return pseudo directories?

I'll elaborate:

In my root directory (public_html) I have a directory named "pages" which contains the following files:

- **example.php**
- **example--abc.php**
- **instance.php**
- **instance--2.php**

Is it possible, using mod_rewrite to acheieve the following:

**example.com/example/** retrieves the file of **/pages/example.php**

**example.com/example/abc/** retrieves the file of **/pages/example--abc.php**

**example.com/instance/** retrieves the file of **/pages/instance.php**

**example.com/instance/2/** retrieves the file of **/pages/instance--2.php**

and so on...?

Thus far I have used the following with success to point /example to /pages/example.php

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !pages/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pages/$1.php [L,QSA]
```

However, it's beyond my current grasp to get the pseudo directories working defined by a double hyphen in the target's filename (--).

I've searched long and hard for a solution to no avail.

Also, the above code doesn't allow for a trailing slash (and it should, in an ideal world)

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks,

JC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based just on description, you can try this:

**UPDATED**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pages
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ pages/$1--$2.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pages
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ pages/$1.php [L]
```

Comment: That works, thanks Xiao!

The root homepage when accessing example.com is trying to fetch example.com/pages/index.php.php

I've been messing around with rewrite conditions trying to make an exception. I tried: 

**DirectoryIndex pages/index.php**

This works, but it seems to affect the behavior of other, deeper sub directories which I have made exempt from your suggested rewrite rule. Any tips?

Comment: @J-C Glad to see it works. Kindly accept answer if this solved issue. Thanks! For the second issue, I think you can add condition to skip rewrite when request is for valid file. This is very common step. I updated the answer to include filename check.